# Parse single XML node in Windows Phone

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

How to parse single xml node in Windows Phone, I have described my web service result in code:

```
    void abcd_Completed(object sender, ServiceReference1.abcdCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       Xdocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    }
```

my e.Result is

```
<root>1234</root>
```

if I run this code in emulator, I am getting the result but in device it returns error like this:

```
"Data at Root level is invalid"
```

how to solve this..I am stuck here.Thanks!!

Comment: That may be caused by a wrong structure of your xml file. First question(stupid), does your xml file has the <?xml ?> node?

Comment: @Olter no, my xml file has not <?xml ?>, I think it takes as a string, so how to read string?

Comment: It takes a string, right. But if you use a XDocument class, you should also check, if the given string satisfies rules for xml file structure. Otherwise, it will throw an error.

Comment: @Olter how do I parse that string, can you show me?

Comment: You XML-parsing is correct. The problem is not with your parsing method, but with your XML file, which has wrong structure. Your web service is giving you the file, which IS NOT a correct XML-file. So, you should check the web service, the problem is in there. Got it?

Comment: @Olter Ok, I understand,thanks brother, but is there any other way to handle that string by my side, because I am not creating web service, I just call the method.So

Comment: @VirajShah, please add to question 1) Your **whole** xml file, you want to be parsed. 2) The result, you want to receive.

Comment: @Olter in my question, e.Result is my whole xml file means <root>1234</root>..is my whole xml file that I am getting as a web service response

Answer (score 0):

**Data at Root level is invalid** most likely means, that xml file has invalid structure.
Note, that each xml file must start with header node:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

If your xml file doesn't have this header, XDocument.Parse method would not parse this file, as an xml.

Also, here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) at MSDN. See, how the xml file should look like.

---

Now, your whole file looks like this:

```
<root>1234</root>
```

It's not an XML file. XML file should look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root>1234</root>
```

Then you can access the root value:

```
string root = doc.Descendants("root").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: I have edited my code, it contains correct node.

Comment: Yeah, I checked your previous question, and saw, it was a typo.

Comment: hey brother, I have edited my web service response and now I am getting XML file with having "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"...but still it is returning same error.
Please help brother

Comment: Eh... Still something should be wrong with your xml file, because I've created similar file and successfully got 1234 value from it. By the way, what is ServiceReference1.abcdCompletedEventArgs type?

Comment: show me your XML file..
here is my new XML file... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>1234</root>

Comment: ServiceReference1.abcdCompletedEventArgs type is "String"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse a XML node you should use [XElement.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse.aspx) instead of the [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx)

But your case is the invalid close tag in your XML code, the `<root>` node has not been closed because the second `<root>` is the next open tag, you should change it to `</root>`

Correct XML is: `<root>1234</root>`

Comment: It contains correct node, I have edited my code, I am really sorry that i forgot to mention that

Comment: Have you tried to parse it by the XElement.Parse method?

Comment: yes.. i have tried but its not working.

Comment: I have tried it on my WP device

Comment: I have tried XElement.Parse, but not working, now I also have my XML file with xml declaration but still it is returning error.